# WooCommerce Product - Programmatically Add Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My Goal: I am using WooCommerce with WCVendor plugin. All vendors have a taxonomy of location. Similarly all products publish by them have taxonomy called 'Product Location'. When vendors add new product, they have to select their location(s) everytime. Now, I would like to run a program that will update their product's location(s) according to their location.

I have managed to get a snippet by searching online -

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'mp_sync_on_product_save', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'mp_sync_on_product_save', 10, 4 );
function mp_sync_on_product_save( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    if ( $meta_key == '_edit_lock' ) { // we've been editing the post
        if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'product' ) { // we've been editing a product
            $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

            // Find the locations of author and save it as product's location

        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help? 
Thank you.

Comment: I have tested WC Vendor plugin and  I don't see that 'Product Location' to be selected every time… There is only a unique "Vendor" metabox and a comission tab in the settings.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have created two taxonomies called LOCATION for profile (custom post type)  and PROCATION (Product Location) for products using code in Functions.php.